# Use column names of a dynamic dataframe as y values of a plot

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
year<-c(2017,2018,2019)
AT1<-c(200,100,0)
AT2<-c(10,100,0)
DT<-data.frame(year,AT1,AT2)

year AT1 AT2
1 2017 200  10
2 2018 100 100
3 2019   0   0
```

Note that my actual dataset has this form

[image]

since the variables are from -1 to 12
Based on this dataframe I create this plot below:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(DT, x = ~factor(year), y = ~AT1, name = 'AT1', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~AT2, name = 'AT2', line = list(color = 'red', width = 4)) %>%
  layout(title = "Day 10 Enrollments",
         xaxis = list(title = "Years"),
         yaxis = list (title = "Count"))
```

The issue is that the `DT` dataframe which I use for my plot may not always include -except from the `years`- the variables `AT1` and `AT2` since it comes after processing another dataframe. For example it may include `AT1`,`AT2` and `AT4` or only `AT2`. If for example here I would add `add_trace(y = ~AT2, name = 'AT2', line = list(color = 'red', width = 4)) %>%` the plot would break since `AT3` does not exist. In the plot I manually set those variables as `y` but I am looking for way to recognize automatically which variables I have in my dataframe and use them as `y`.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gather` the AT columns:

```
DT<-tidyr::gather(DT,"AT", "value", -year)
```

Now we use the fact that plotly automatically splits the data based on the `name` variable for creating different traces for each group:

```
plot_ly(DT, x = ~year, y = ~value, name = ~AT, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(width = 4)) %>%
    layout(title = "Day 10 Enrollments",
           xaxis = list(title = "Years"),
           yaxis = list (title = "Count"))
```

Result:

[image]

Exact same code running on the data you provided as an image (using those column names):

[image]

Comment: I had not thought that the variables name might cause an issue but I editted to show their exact form

Comment: I don't understand the problem. My solution will work regardless of the names of the variables (so long as the only other column is called `year`). Just tried it with the new data you provided and it still works. (see image added to my answer)

Comment: oK I will accept it. It would be nice if in the color bar I could have names like "-1","0" etc insetad of "X.1" etc

Comment: You can call the columns whatever you want - just rename them, or rename the values of the AT column after gathering by whatever algorithm makes sense to you.